# Ajax call return 404

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm doing a contact form with wordpress. I'm using 3 files to perform the task:

1. **parts/contact_form.php:** is the file that contains the contact form. It's called from index.php using `<?php get_template_part('parts/contact_form'); ?>`
2. **js/theme.js:** it contains the theme functions, so it have the ajax call to the PHP script.
3. **php/mail.php:** contains the php script to send the email with the info passed by ajax.

The problem is that the AJAX call return 404 (Not found), so I suppose that wordpress is looking a page with the AJAX url `php/mail.php`.

The contact form:

```
<form method="post" action="#" class="conForms" id="contactForm">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="con_name" id="con_name" class="inputa required <?php if ($_POST['submitted'] && !$name_surname) echo 'textbox-error'; ?>" placeholder="Nombre y apellido" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['con_name']); ?>"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="con_phone" id="con_phone" class="inputa required <?php if ($emptyPhone == TRUE) echo 'textbox-error'; ?>" placeholder="Teléfono" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['con_phone']); ?>"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="email" name="con_email" id="con_email" class="inputa required <?php if ($emptyPhone == TRUE) echo 'textbox-error'; ?>" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['con_email']); ?>"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="con_company" id="con_company" class="inputa <?php if ($_POST['submitted'] && !$company) echo 'textbox-error'; ?>" placeholder="Empresa" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['con_company']); ?>"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="texputa required <?php if ($_POST['submitted'] && !$message) echo 'textbox-error'; ?>" name="con_message" id="con_message" placeholder="Mensaje"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['con_message']); ?></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
            <button type="submit" class="submita" id="con_submit">Enviar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

the js script:

```
  // ========================
  // Contact Submit
  // ========================
  if ($("#contactForm").length > 0)
  {
    $("#contactForm").on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#con_submit").html('Processing...');
      var con_name = $("#con_name").val();
      var con_email = $("#con_email").val();
      var con_phone = $("#con_phone").val();
      var con_message = $("#con_message").val();
      var con_company = '';
      if ($("#con_company").length > 0)
      {
        con_company = $("#con_company").val();
      }


      var required = 0;
      $(".required", this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '')
        {
          $(this).addClass('reqError');
          required += 1;
        }
        else
        {
          if ($(this).hasClass('reqError'))
          {
            $(this).removeClass('reqError');
            if (required > 0)
            {
              required -= 1;
            }
          }
        }
      });
      if (required === 0)
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'php/mail.php',
          data: {con_company: con_company, con_name: con_name, con_email: con_email, con_phone: con_phone, con_message: con_message},
          success: function(data)
          {
            alert(data);
            $("#con_submit").html('Done!');
            $("#contactForm input, #contactForm textarea").val('');
            $(".contactSuccess").fadeIn('slow');
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(".contactSuccess").fadeOut('slow');
            }, 2500);
          },
          error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,3));
          }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        $("#con_submit").html('Failed!');
      }
    });
```

and the PHP script:

```
<?php

$emptyEmail = FALSE;
$emptyPhone = FALSE;

//response messages
$missing_content = "<p>Please supply all information.</p>";
$email_invalid   = "<p class=\"error\">This does not seem to be an e-mail address.</p>";
$phone_invalid   = "<p class=\"error\">This does not seem to be a valid pohne number.</p>";
$message_unsent  = "<p class=\"error\">Message was not sent. Try Again.</p>";
$message_sent    = "<p>Thanks! Your message has been sent.</p>";

//user posted variables
$name_surname = $_POST['con_name'];
$phone        = $_POST['con_phone'];
$email        = $_POST['con_email'];
$company      = $_POST['con_company'];
$message      = $_POST['con_message'];

//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "Someone sent a message from " . get_bloginfo('name') . " > Contact Home";
$headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

if(!$_POST['submitted']) contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
//validate email
else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo 1;
  $emptyEmail = TRUE;
}
// validate phone number (Spain)
$expresion = '/^[9|6|7][0-9]{8}$/';
if(!preg_match($expresion, $phone)){
   echo 2;
 }

else { //email is valid // phone is valid
  //validate presence of name and message
  if (empty($name_surname) || empty($message)) {
    echo 3;
  }
  else { //ready to go!

    $message = "from " . $name_surname. " (" . $email . ") of company " . $company . "\r\n\r\n" .
    "message:\r\n" . $message;

    $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
    if($sent) echo 0; //message sent!
    else echo 4; //message wasn't sent
  }
}
```

Comment: If you read the Wordpress Codex on AJAX (https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), you will find how to set the `url` and `action` variables. Try implementing what is in the instructions and see if that doesn't help.